# How to change the delay of a Timer for every time it runs?

Tags: java, timer, runtime, delay

Right now I have a timer that has a delay of 5 seconds, however I need a different delay after it has run once.
I am going through some pictures and during the first round it should show them for 5 seconds. After that it should show them for 10 seonds. How is it possible to change the delay of a Timer during runtime?

What has to happen:

- Start Timer
- Run for 5 seconds
- Change delay
- Run for 10 seconds

Comment: duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386545/java-timer-with-not-fixed-delay

Comment: Which `Timer`?  `java.util.Timer` or `javax.swing.Timer`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some code!

You need to check if the timer has 5 seconds make it 10 and so on.

```
int delayTime = 5;
//run first delay
if (delayTime == 5){
delayTime = 10;
}
```

This is some code for the idea, don't know how it looks in your project.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approach for your use case:

First Approach:

Like say I want to show the picture for 1000 seconds. So I will execute for loop till 1000 seconds; or if you want to run it infinitely then you can change the condition in for loop. Below code will execute the for loop after every 5 seconds delay.

```
int delayTimeInMiliSec;
    for(int delayTime = 5 ; delayTime<=1000; delayTime = delayTime+5){
        delayTimeInMiliSec = delayTime * 1000;
        // here Call your method that shows pictures
        Thread.sleep(delayTimeInMiliSec);
    }
```

Second Approach:

1. create a class extending TimerTask(available in java.util package). TimerTask is a abstract class.
2. Write your code in public void run() method that you want to execute periodically.

Code sample:

```
  import java.util.TimerTask;

    // Create a class extends with TimerTask
    public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

        // Add your task here
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //show pictures code
        }
    }

import java.util.Timer;

public class SchedulerMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
        ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
        time.schedule(st, 0, 5000); // Create Repetitively task for every 5 secs


    }
}
```