# How do I make timer.schedule()'s period change every time it runs the TimerTask?

Tags: java, random, timer

```
timer.schedule(new PressTask(), 2000, rand);
```

I want the above to have rand be a different number every time it excecutes. For example, the first time timer.*schedule* is called, let's say *rand* is 5345. The next time that it is called, it should be a different number, not 5345. How would I do this?

Pardon the messy coding, this was just a little practice I made for myself.

```
public class Keypress 
{
    static Timer timer = new Timer();
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JButton btn = new JButton("start");
    static JButton btn2 = new JButton("stop");
    static JTextField txt = new JTextField();
    static Robot robot;
    static Random couch = new Random();
    static int rand = couch.nextInt(10000 - 5000) + 5000;

   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
System.out.println(rand);

frame.setSize(500,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
btn.addActionListener(new startPress());
btn2.addActionListener(new stopPress());
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
frame.add(btn);
frame.add(btn2);
frame.add(txt);

try 
{
    robot = new Robot();
} 
catch (AWTException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
frame.setVisible(true);
}
static class startPress implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        timer.schedule(new PressTask(), 2000, rand);
    }
}
public static class PressTask extends TimerTask
{
public void run()
{
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
}
}
static class stopPress implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This might be your answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386545/java-timer-with-not-fixed-delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386545/java-timer-with-not-fixed-delay)

Comment: Your code gives a different number for rand each time it runs

Comment: @downeyt thanks, this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead of a `Timer`?

```
public ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
public Random rand = new Random();    

class Repeater implements Runnable{
    private Runnable task;
    private long interval;
    private long maxInterval;
    private TimeUnit unit;
    public Repeater(Runnable task, long maxInterval, TimeUnit unit){
        this.task = task;
        this.interval = (rand.nextLong())%maxInterval //don't let interval be more than maxInterval
        this.unit = unit;
        this.maxInterval = maxInterval;
    }

    public void run(){
        executor.schedule(new Repeater(task,maxInterval,unit)
            , interval, unit);
    }
}

class startPress implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        int maxIntervalMs = 5000;
        executor.schedule( new Repeater(new PressTask(),initialIntervalMs,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            , rand.nextLong()%maxIntervalMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

**Note**: You can actually do the same thing with a `Timer` rather than a `ScheduledExecutorService`, but the wonderful book "Java Concurrency in Practice" recommends the use of `ScheduledExecutorService` over `Timer` for a number of reasons, including for example, better handling if an exception is thrown from the task and a more flexible api.